# Chrome extension: Memory data

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I was wondering with Google Chrome's extension API, is it possible to extract memory usage data for each tab and use it in a popup? I know there is this extension https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mmbijkbkjlefoimjopcojbkpnmljahlh but all it does is simply open the about:memory tab. I was thinking maybe there was a way to "parse" the about:memory tab and use it for my extension. Or am I delusional and this is not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API and chrome:// scheme is forbidden for extensions so you can't parse that page either...

- XMLHttpRequest calls to chrome:// are not allowed
- Content scripts are not injected under chrome://

Comment: Have you looked at the experimental API by any chance? There is this method,http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/experimental.processes.html, but I'm not sure if it will help at all.

Comment: @Albinoswordfish Yes that's the place where it should be, but it just returns process id for now...

Comment: It's possible to allow extensions to access `chrome://` URLs via `chrome://flags`

Answer (score 1):

The `chrome.processes` API can be used to obtain the same data that the Task Manager uses: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes