# Retrieving memory consumption from a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

we developed a simple crawler for Chromium which works fine for the fist ~12h and then crashes. I believe that this is due to memory consumption and it eventually running out of such. However, this is hard to debug because once the extension has crashed, chrome://memory does not show information on how much it had used anymore.

Thus, I was wondering if there is any chance to get the information that is shown on chrome://memory and frequently report it to a central server for monitoring? XHR on chrome://memory doesn't work since

> Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.

I am working with Chrome 37.0.2016.0 canary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chrome extension: Memory data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508119/chrome-extension-memory-data)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like it.

[Chrome extension: Memory data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508119/chrome-extension-memory-data)

The experimental API is a 404. At least that's what I get.

Comment: A dirty hack might also be to to go chrome://flags and enable "Extensions on chrome:// URLs", which would allow me to script into the chrome://memory page and send the info to my background script. But that is really just dirty ;)

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/processes#event-onUpdatedWithMemory has the necessary information. Only works on the dev channel though